# What is lambda unit in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda

I'm a haskell beginner and trying to understand this definition of a counter based on a StateMonad. I know lambdas usually have variables, e.g.

```
(\n -> n + 1)
```

is a function  that takes an argument `n`, increments its value by 1, and returns the result. However, in this case instead of a variable there's a value, an empty tuple (unit).

```
tick :: StateMonad Int Int
tick = fetch >>= (\n -> store (n + 1) >>= (\() -> return n))
```

It's taken from [Generalising Monads to Arrows](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4575) page 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, the arguments to a lambda expression are actually patterns in Haskell (check out the first case of the EBNF for `exp` in the [Haskell 98 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html)). So I can write a function like `\(x,y) -> x + y` which does the same thing as `\t -> fst t + snd t`. In this case, `\() -> return n` is pattern matching on the only possible value of type `()` - `()` itself.

---

Here's the analogy spelled out explicitly. The same way I can write a function

```
f :: Num a => (a,a) -> a
f t = fst t + snd t
```

I can also write this function using [pattern matching](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)

```
f' :: Num a => (a,a) -> a
f' (x,y) = x + y
```

Well the same holds for lambda expressions: I could write `\(x,y) -> x + y`. Then, the lambda `\() -> return n` is the same thing, except that pattern matching on values of type `()` is trivial: the only possible value is `()`.

### EDIT

Just in case it isn't clear, `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` is regular function that puts a value into a minimal monadic context, nothing to do with the `return` keyword present in many imperative languages.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why would you need pattern matching for a single value that you know apriori.

Comment: @dimid You don't. I guess it makes the code a bit cleaner. You might not want to write `\x -> return n` because then the reader goes looking for where `x` is used when in reality it is just thrown away.

Comment: I see, so can it be simplified to `tick = fetch >>= (\n -> store (n + 1) >>= (return n))`?

Comment: @dimid No: `return n` is the monadic action that does nothing interesting and produces `n`, whereas `\() -> return n` (or `\x -> return n` or `\_ -> return n`) is the function that ignores its argument, then does nothing interesting and produces `n`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, thanks, now I finally understand it.
Alec, could you add Daniel's comment to your answer?

Comment: @DanielWagner `\() -> ...` does _not_ ignore its argument, unlike the other two. It evaluates the argument and compares it to `()`. `(\_ -> 0) undefined` is `0`; `(\() -> 0) undefined` throws an error.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That's true in theory, but generally not in practice. Pattern matching on `()` is pretty much always written just to clarify that the unit type really is what's being used, rather than because the difference between `\_ -> ` and `\() ->` is expected to matter. It's almost never used as "this could be `()`, or it could be a nonterminating value, and I'll check to make sure it's `()`"; checking for that by pattern matching is pretty useless because you don't actually get to *handle* the error case if there is one; you just make a bigger error.

Comment: Using `(\ () -> ...)` instead of `(\ _ -> ...)` is a clarity that has a performance cost.  There has to be a call to evaluate the argument (unless the compiler can prove it's already evaluated), which is cheap, but not free.

Comment: you can use `>>` instead of `>>=` in cases where the previous value isn't used. e.g. `tick = fetch >>= \n -> store (n + 1) >> return n`